# Как продублировать символ с помощью printf

Tags: c, printf, оформление

```
printf ("%c", 196);
```

Как мне сделать так, что символ был напечатан не 1 раз, а допустим 5 раз, чтобы избежать таких строк

```
printf ("%c%c%c%c%c, 196, 196, 196, 196, 196);
```

Сторонние библиотеки юзать нельзя, тольк

Comment: связанный вопрос: [How to repeat a char using printf?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14678948/4279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так не устроит?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) putchar(196);
```

Ну, или

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) printf("%c",196);
```

P.S. Если бы работать в C++, то там символ-заполнитель можно указать -

```
char k = 'a';
cout << setfill(k) << setw(5) << k << endl;
```

Но это так, досужие рассуждения, так как вопрос именно о C...

Comment: для C, лучше цикла вероятно не придумаешь (`printf()` формата нет, а `memset()` это преждевременная оптимизация -- сам компилятор может сообразить как простой цикл собрать). На C++, [можно `std::cout << std::string(5, 42) << std::endl;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7897163/4279)